# can i use Java Fx web view in Java SE?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, java-8

i am working with java SE application, but i want to add a web view inside my application (or any other suggestion to view online web content inside JFrame) but it should work as good as web view, please guys help me out

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: thanks man, required answer was there thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to integrate JavaFX controls in Swing components, but AFAIK getting the details right such event handling etc. is a bit tricky.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_swing.htm#JFXIP561

Comment: thanks man, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
There is nice example at [Oracle's site](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).

Thankfully to interaction [WebEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) you can also customise interface, layout, tabs and much more.
Here is a simple example how to load content into WebView:

```
final String url = "https://www.wikipedia.org/";
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.load(url);
```

Comment: thanks for help but not met my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [JScrollPane(JEditorPane)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) , you might want to look at That.

Or Try **JxBrowser** , JxBrowser can be used to display modern web pages and HTML+CSS+JavaScript content in your Java applications. It allows building GUI of your cross-desktop application using any popular HTML5 UI toolkit.

See this : http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-browser-your-java-swing.